# pandas.read_csv Error: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2

Tags: python

I have problem here i want to read some csv and store it in variable with python pandas this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("GlobalTemperatures.csv")
```

and this is the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CParserError                              Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-5-eb2bcd3c4f37> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv("GlobalTemperatures.csv")

(pandas/parser.c:10415)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory 
(pandas/parser.c:10691)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows 
(pandas/parser.c:11437)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows 
(pandas/parser.c:11308)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error 
(pandas/parser.c:27037)()

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in 
line 6, saw 2
```

please, any suggestion?

Comment: Can you check line 6 of your file `GlobalTemperatures.csv`. It is expecting 1 column but seems like line 6 has two column or 2 commas. If possible could you add to your question the line 4, 5, 6, 7 of your CSV file if it doesn't contain any sensitive data?

Comment: Can you show the first 10 lines of your csv file?